# I'm using mybatis, but the select value is null

Tags: spring-boot, oracle11g, mybatis

I have configured a simple member login and the search return value is null

In DAO, the return value of selectOne in sqlSession is null.
insert statement works fine
can i know the solution?

loginPage.html

```
 <form action="/memberLogin" method="post" class="login100-form validate-form">
                                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-26" data-validate="Username is required">
                                    <span class="label-input100">Username</span>
                                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="member_name" placeholder="Enter username">
                                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-18" data-validate = "Password is required">
                                    <span class="label-input100">Password</span>
                                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="member_pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
                                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="flex-sb-m w-full p-b-30">
                                    <div class="contact100-form-checkbox">
                                        <input class="input-checkbox100" id="ckb1" type="checkbox" name="remember-me">
                                        <label class="label-checkbox100" for="ckb1">
                                            Remember me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <a href="#" class="txt1">
                                            Forgot Password?
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                                    <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">
                                        login
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" id = "loginBtn" class="login100-form-btn"><a href="/signUp">
                                        signUp</a>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

MemberController

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/memberLogin")
    public String login(MemberDTO memberDTO, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(3600);
        System.out.println("세션 아이디 : " + session.getId());
        System.out.println("세션 유효시간 : " + session.getMaxInactiveInterval());

        System.out.println("memberDTO : " + memberDTO);
        MemberDTO member = memberService.login(memberDTO);

        System.out.println("member : " + member);

        if (member != null){
            session.setAttribute("member", member);
            System.out.println("로그인 성공");

            return "redirect:/";
        } else {
            System.out.println("로그인 실패");
            return "redirect:login";
        }
    }
```

MemberService

```
@Override
public MemberDTO login(MemberDTO memberDTO) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("login Service : " + memberDTO);
    return memberDAO.login(memberDTO);
}
```

MemberDAO

```
 @Override
    public MemberDTO login(MemberDTO memberDTO) throws Exception {
        MemberDTO member = null;
        System.out.println("DAO : " + memberDTO);
        member =  sqlSession.selectOne(NAMESPACE + "loginCheck", memberDTO);
        System.out.println("dao : " + member);
        return sqlSession.selectOne(NAMESPACE + "loginCheck", memberDTO);
    }
```

MemberDTO

```
public class MemberDTO {
    private String member_name;
    private String member_pwd;
    private String member_email;
    private String member_role;
    private Date member_register_datetime;

    public String getMember_name() {
        return member_name;
    }

    public void setMember_name(String member_name) {
        this.member_name = member_name;
    }

    public String getMember_pwd() {
        return member_pwd;
    }

    public void setMember_pwd(String member_pwd) {
        this.member_pwd = member_pwd;
    }

    public String getMember_email() {
        return member_email;
    }

    public void setMember_email(String member_email) {
        this.member_email = member_email;
    }

    public String getMember_role() {
        return member_role;
    }

    public void setMember_role(String member_role) {
        this.member_role = member_role;
    }

    public Date getMember_register_datetime() {
        return member_register_datetime;
    }

    public void setMember_register_datetime(Date member_register_datetime) {
        this.member_register_datetime = member_register_datetime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MemberDTO{" +
                "member_name='" + member_name + '\'' +
                ", member_pwd='" + member_pwd + '\'' +
                ", member_email='" + member_email + '\'' +
                ", member_role='" + member_role + '\'' +
                ", member_register_datetime=" + member_register_datetime +
                '}';
    }
}
```

MemberMapper.xml

```
<mapper namespace="member">

    <insert id = "signUp" parameterType="com.withstudy.domain.MemberDTO">
        insert into MEMBER
        values (#{member_email, jdbcType = VARCHAR}, #{member_pwd, jdbcType = VARCHAR},  #{member_name, jdbcType = VARCHAR}, 'General', sysdate)
    </insert>

    <select id = "loginCheck" parameterType="com.withstudy.domain.MemberDTO" resultType="com.withstudy.domain.MemberDTO">
        SELECT * FROM MEMBER
        WHERE MEMBER_NAME = #{member_name, jdbcType = VARCHAR}
        AND MEMBER_PWD = #{member_pwd, jdbcType = VARCHAR}
    </select>
</mapper>
```

Oracle DB(SQL Developer)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3sdQ.png)

Console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwBxg.png)

Comment: Enable TRACE level logging and add the output to the question. It will contain the SQL, parameters and result set.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to list columns that you are expected to map on your Entity in SELECT statement. You can accidentally pull something big and query performance may degradates. So try to list them first:

```
SELECT 
   member_name,
   member_pwd,
   member_email,
   member_role,
   member_register_datetime;
FROM MEMBER
WHERE MEMBER_NAME = #{member_name, jdbcType = VARCHAR}
AND MEMBER_PWD = #{member_pwd, jdbcType = VARCHAR}
```